# Error when converting XML to CSV in command line

Tags: linux, xml, csv, xslt, command-line

I am trying to find all `.xml` file in a Linux directory and convert them to `.csv` by:

```
find . -name "*xml" -execdir sh -c 'xsltproc -o "${0%.xml}.csv" opv.xsl "$0"' {} \;
```

but the following error occurred:

```
warning: failed to load external entity "opv.xsl"
cannot parse opv.xsl
```

I have already installed the `xsltproc` package by `conda install -c anaconda libxslt`.

Comment: opv.xsl is an input style sheet and application cannot locate the input file.

Comment: And where does `opv.xsl` reside? Have you tried providing the fully qualified path to it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use `-exec` rather than `-execdir`. The difference is that `-execdir` executes the command in the directory containing each found file, but those directories won't contain your stylesheet. Alternatively, provide a full path to the stylesheet file.